# how to find out the coordinates of an item in a gridview Android

Tags: android, gridview, coordinates

I would like to find out how to find the coordinates (x,y) of a gridview that the user clicks on based on the returned position?

```
    0 1 2 
    3 4 5
    6 7 8
```

if i use 4 as the selected item i can work out that it is on row 1

```
 4 / columnLength(3) = 1.3 etc
```

but whats the best way to calclate the column?
or is there some built in methods that i can take advantage of?

Comment: Why can't you use an `onClick` to get which item you're clicking on? Is there a reason you need to have the X,Y coordinates?  And is the X,Y coordinates of the screen or in relation to the entire gridview?

Comment: yea i need the coordinates of the grid. 

the onlick will only give me the position not the coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first we need to define a few things

```
int numberOfColumns;//should be able to get this from the view
int numberOfRows = Math.ceil(items.Count / numberOfColumns);
```

then we can figure out the position

```
int row = Math.ceil((position + 1) / numberOfColumns);
int column = (row * numberOfColumns) - position;
```

that should do it

Comment: Why define numberOfRows if you don't use it?

Comment: I ended up not needing it, but you still might want to know how so I left it in.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Should that be Math.ceil((position+1)/numberOfColumns)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, although I've never done it before.

```
GridView gv = new GridView(this);
gv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        event.getX();
        event.getY();
    }
});
```

Comment: so if i used that method in the grid above and select "6" would the row be 3 and the column be 0?

Comment: No, sorry. I thought you were asking for the actual X and Y coordinates of where the click occurred.  The way you are doing would be the best way.  There is no method to get the column/row.

Answer (score 0):

y = position - (x*columnLength);